# How to push helm packages in a chartmuseum through a ci-cd pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm

i want to configure a ci-cd pipeline, that should contains a stage for placing the helm charts in a chartmuseum (which is in an aws s3 Bucket for example).
i have already the operation configured with helm s3 plugin(which uses aws s3 as a helm repository and push direct the charts into it through the pipeline execution:

```
$ helm s3 push CHART_NAME.tgz REPO_NAME
```

so i do not want to push them direct in s3, i want instead to push these packages to a chartmuseum.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have stood up your charmuseum instance, add something like the following lines to your CI/CD pipeline.

`helm repo add chartmuseum http://[host]`

`helm push chart/ chartmuseum`

Or push a particular version:
`helm push chart/ --version="[version]" chartmuseum`

Docs from:
https://github.com/chartmuseum/helm-push

Comment: thank you for your answer. just a last thing: can i use the repo in this case as an AWS s3, like this : $ helm repo add chartmuseum s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$CHARTS_DIR_NAME